# How to know the current script FullName

Tags: powershell, path

My script call many other script and i need know each fullname (for log info).

but the same command doesn't work in Powershell_ISE

Answer (score 2):

This code are avaible in Powershell_ISE and in script.ps1 file

```
function Get-ScriptFullName () { 
    if($hostinvocation -ne $null) {
        $hostinvocation.MyCommand.path
    } else {
        $script:MyInvocation.MyCommand.path
    }
}
```